# Why the time complexity of this function is O(n^3)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I’m not sure what the function would be but I thought it would be in O(n^4). Why is it in O(n^3) when only the inner loop is in O(n^3) and the outer loop is in O(n).

This is the code:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i > n - 6) {
        for (int j= 0; j< n*n*n; j++) { sum -= j; }
    }
}
```

Comment: To elaborate on the comment above: `(i > n - 6)` will be true only in 6 of the outer iterations, and so the inner loop will run only 6 times, which is O(1). Therefore the overall complexity is O(n^3).

Comment: Why is it O(n^3) then and not O(n)?

Comment: Because as you observed, the inner loop itself is O(n^3).

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop has **O(n)** iterations (as you observed).

But the inner loop is only executed in **O(1)** of these oterations (6 to be precise), due to the `if`:

```
if (i > n - 6)
```

The inner loop has an **O(n<sup>3</sup>)** complexity (again as you observed).

But since it is executed only **O(1)** times, the overall complexity is also **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided could be rewritten like this without altering the time complexity:

```c
int sum = 0;
for (int i = n; i >= 0 && i > n - 6; i--) {
    for (int j= 0; j< n*n*n; j++) { sum -= j; }
}
for (int i = n - 6; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Do nothing
}
```

The first (outer) loop iterates 6 times, so we have 6 times O(³), which still is O(³).

The second loop iterates −6 times and performs nothing else than comparing the value of `i` in O(1) time, so that is O(−6), which is O().

So in total we have O(³) + O(), which is O(³).